# python regex matching specific word only, not a subset

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to search for specific words using regex in python.

```
lst2 = ['Azmat', 'AZ', 'azim', 'Zard', 'Zardari']

pattern = re.compile(r"\bAZ|Zard\b", re.I)

for item in lst2:
    if re.search(pattern, item):
        print item
```

This code produces:

```
Azmat
AZ
azim
Zard
```

Why is it not matching "AZ" and "Zard" only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is looking for a word starting with `az` or finishing with `zard`. Fix it like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\b(AZ|Zard)\b", re.I)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because your regex is matching either:

```
\bAZ
```

OR

```
Zard\b
```

Use a non-capture group to limit the 'influence' of the `|` operator:

```
\b(?:AZ|Zard)\b
```

This way, it reads: `\b` then either `AZ` OR `Zard` and last `\b`.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(AZ|Zard)$", re.I)
```

better show start and end of string with `^` and `$`

Comment: whats the diff b/w `r"\b(AZ|Zard)\b"` & `r"^(AZ|Zard)$"` ?

Comment: For your example, none, but `^` means "the beginning of the string" and `$` "the end of the string". It won't work if you have more than one word in the string.

Comment: First can find matches `AZ` or `Zard` in string `qwe AZ wdwq Zard dawg aw`. Second pattern is match only if string is exactly `AZ` or `Zard`